# Android - From Canvas to Bitmap to improve rendering

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm going crazy around this problem about days.

I've created a custom View that in onDraw() method draws some shapes and text. Because the drawn dimension is bigger than the custom view, I had to override onMeasure() method to implement scrolling.

Activity works fine, scrolling is OK, but because in onDraw() method some big operations are executed, navigation in Activity is very slow. These operations must be executed in on Draw() method. Scroll causes the redrawn of the View so onDraw() method is called frequently.

The content of custom View changes dynamically, it depends by some selections made by the user through precedent Activity.

So I've thought to convert my Canvas into a Bitmap but there are some problem.

1) I can't know width and height parameters for Bitmap.createBitmap() before creating the Canvas. I can know them after onDraw() method. So I can't associate a Bitmap to the Canvas.

2) If I try to set the dimension of the bitmap manually it throws an OutOfMemory exception: my Canvas is very bigger due by the size of the shapes.

So, what can I have to do?

The onDraw() method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(!listaTl.isEmpty())
    {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);      
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
        p.setAntiAlias(true);   
        p.setStrokeWidth(1);
        for(TimelineGrafica t : listaTl)
        {
            if(inseritaLaPrima)
                 y = ySalvata + this.yAngoloDestroGiu + DISTANZA_FRA_TIMELINE;
            p.setColor(t.getColor());
            disegnaPunta(canvas,p,t);
            disegnaRettangolo(canvas,p,t);
            disegnaGrain(canvas,p,t);
            disegnaFatti(canvas,p,t);
            inseritaLaPrima = true;
        }
        y = ySalvata;
        inseritaLaPrima = false;
    }
    requestLayout();
}
```

Methods "disegna*" contain some canvas.draw*() statements.
Here the XML file associates to the Activity that contains the Custom View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/vScroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:overScrollMode="always" 
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
>
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="always" 
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
>
<AppAndroid.RappresentazioneTimeline.TimelineView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
/>


</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why can't you adjust the dimensions of your drawn items to the bounds of your view?

Comment: My application consists in a representation of some timelines that contain some facts above them. If I adjust the dimensions of the drawn to the bounds of the View, timelines will be drawn shorter than their original size and facts (that are touchable) will be drawn one over the other.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do.  Can you attach your source?  Include the layout file that references your custom view if you have one.

Comment: I edited the post adding some code.

Comment: One thing I notice is calling requestLayout from within onDraw will definitely cause problems.  If you need to cause your view to redraw itself, you should do it from someplace else where you know that something has changed that would cause it to render differently than the last time.  You can do this by calling the invalidate(); method on your custom view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But doesn't the Custom View have to redraw itself when there's scrolling? So I've to call invalidate() method when I intercept some scrolling events. But where can I intercept them?

Comment: It's true that the custom view is responsible for its drawing.  However, you can expect the parent scroll view will handle invalidating its child when scrolling occurs (which in turn will call your onDraw method.)  You should keep track of the clip bounds you get from your Canvas as that will indicate how much of your drawing area Android really needs you to update.  Have a look at Canvas.getClipBounds() for more information about that.